# ng-Select Option set default value from list if value match using angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have html.

```
<select  ng-model="user.role" class="form-control" name="role" >
    <option value="">Select Role</option><option ng-repeat="role in roles" value="{{role.authority}}">{{role.authority}}</option> </select>
```

Now roles is a list and role.authority is string. i want to set default selected if role.authority==MYROLE then set to default, which is in role.authority.

How can i do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to assign the same value to `select` model inside controller, in your case it would be something like this

```
$scope.user.role = $scope.roles[0].authority
```

or with use of ngSelected

```
<option ng-repeat="role in roles" value="{{role.authority}}" ng-selected="role.authority == 'defaultValue'">{{role.authority}}</option>
```

Comment: its, $scope.roles=data.roles. here roles is list of role object.

Comment: In HTML i pass selected = "someValue", but i don't pass it hard coded. i want to check if role.authority contains "SOMEROLE" then set to to default selected.

Comment: yes, so after this line you can assign `$scope.user.role = $scope.roles[0].authority` where `0` is your default role

Comment: no its not like that, i want to do like ng-if(role.authority=="ROLENAME") then this is selected, and when i call this it give me selected data. this time i select role to perform action. now can i set something as default from my list after check in ng-if or something like that

Comment: can you send me link where you used this please.